# Share intent like default photo app in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, share, uiactivityviewcontroller, airdrop

Hello I am developing an app, In which I have to integrate sharing Intent.
I want to do sharing intent same as default Photo App.
I have implemented below code but it doesn't work properly.

```
- (IBAction)shareButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
    self.activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[self.textField.text] applicationActivities:nil];
    [self presentViewController:self.activityViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

[image: sharing in default Photo app]

[image: sharing in my app]

In my app facebook share icon doesn't display while in photo app it displays.
Please help me.

Comment: Login with facebook in your settings, then it will display facebook icon.

Comment: @Ashish I know that but in Photo app facebook icon comes even i didn't login in setting account.

Comment: yes, I am not sure but If you run the code in iOS 7 it will display the facebook button also.

Comment: I have attached iOS 8.1.2 screen shots and it behave same in iOS 7.0.1